# Execute interactive script in linux before login

Tags: bash, embedded-linux, boot, login-script

I need to execute a script, which prints out a license agreement to user after booting and ideally before logging in. The user needs to accept this license to continue. On negative response the system should reboot/turn off.

If the license is accepted, it shouldn't be printed on next reboot.

I've made some research and found several ways. One way is to use a `systemd` service, another says to use `/etc/rc.local` or putting the script into `profile.d`

I've tried executing the script which prints the EULA license and prompts for accepting/rejecting it from `rc.local`, however, without success.

So I've tried the `profile.d`, which seems to be fine, however, this happens after logging in.

So out of curiosity, which approach is the preferred one? Is it even possible to execute an interactive script before the user is logged in?

Thanks for help,
Renegade

Comment: Print the license from `rc.local`, get user confirmation from `profile.d`? Or just print it twice.